# Rails: Adding unique index with migration throws Mysql2::Error: BLOB/TEXT

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-migrations

I have this models:

## ofert.rb

```
class Ofert < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
validates_uniqueness_of :reference, scope: :user_id
end
```

## user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :oferts
end
```

I want to validate the uniqueness of the attribute `reference` scoped by `user_id`, I mean, the same user can't have a product with the same reference, but the reference can be repeated if it's not the same user.

as you can see there is a `validates_uniqueness_of` statement in the `Ofert` model, then I added this migration:

`add_index(:oferts, [:reference, :user_id], unique: true)`

However when I run the migration I get the following error:

```
Mysql2::Error: BLOB/TEXT column 'reference' used in key specification without a key length: CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `index_oferts_on_reference_and_user_id`  ON `oferts` (`reference`, `user_id`)
```

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since :reference is a text or blob column, you must specify a length for the index:

```
add_index :oferts, [:reference, :user_id], unique: true, length: 10
```

There are maximum length limits that depend on the database engine you are using, so double check the [MySQL index documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/column-indexes.html).

Comment: What is the difference if I only specify a length for `:reference` ? `length: {reference: 6}`

Comment: The difference is that if you only specify a single length, that length will be used for each column. Or you can specify each column's index length separately as you mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for you help, you rock!